# Http4s EntityDecoder not being auto derived for simple case class

Tags: circe, http4s, http4s-circe

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot decode into a value of type com.blah.rest.model.UserProfile, 
because no EntityDecoder[cats.effect.IO, com.blah.rest.model.UserProfile] 
instance could be found.
```

for the following case class:

```
case class UserProfile(id: Option[Int], firstName: String, lastName: String)
```

Encountered the error on `POST` code:

```
case req @ POST -> Root / "v1" / "profiles" =>
  req.as[UserProfile] flatMap {(up: UserProfile) =>
    Ok(service.createProfile(up).asJson)
  }
```

With the following `POST` body:

```
{
   "firstName": "Jack",
   "lastName": "Appleseed"
}
```

I think this happens when the body is being converted to `UserProfile` in `req.as[UserProfile]`!

But, this is a plain vanilla case class, the `EntityDecoder` should be auto-derived! I know `akka-http` does it!

Any ideas/suggestions?

Please Note:   `Http4sVersion  = "0.18.0-M4"` and `circe version "0.9.0-M1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this dependency: 
`"io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.9.1"`

resolved the auto-encoding of case classes to JSON for me.

It allows for the required import: `import io.circe.generic.auto._`

Comment: You should really try not to use the `io.circe.generic.auto._`. It has multiple problems. One of the biggest is that the encoder/decoder is derived at the call site, so it's impossible to implement a test for it.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

```
req.decodeJson[UserProfile] flatMap {(up: UserProfile) =>
    Ok(service.createProfile(up).asJson)
  }
```

The reason you get that is the bridge from a Circe decoder to an http4s EntityDecoder is not implicit. You can make one if you're purely a JSON API, but that's not an assumption the library can generally make.

Comment: I'm getting similar issue but with error `value flatMap is not a member of type parameter F[Order]`